# Report and Dashboards

Tags: dashboard, custom-reports, report-chart, einstein-analytics-dashboards

I am a salesforce administrator. I have created a matrix report. I need to display the report in dashboard with row and column grouping without chart. But dashboard is not allowing to group by row and column. Is there any way to show the report as a Matrix table in dashboard?

Can someone help me on this? TIA

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Currently, it's not possible. Here's an idea you can vote on for this functionality: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kluUAAQ

This is really an old idea almost 9 years but still pending. I don't know why salesforce hasn't implemented it yet.

Note - A small workaround
If this is a report that users will reference often, you could either have them favorite the report or add a link to the report on the home page.

I hope this will resolve your doubt.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not to mention, completely my pleasure. I hope the workaround resolves your issue, at least temporarily.